# How to handle columns of data in a responsive manner?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a page with 2 columns of news articles that display vertically down the page. Note that both columns are styled differently. Eg. Column A has a different width than Column B.

```
A1 B1
A2 B2
A3 B3
|  | 
An Bn
```

Both columns are divs. I have coded the website responsive so that when you resize the browser window to a small width, the whole B column gets shifted under the A column.

```
A1
A2
A3
| 
An
B1
B2
B3
|
Bn
```

The whole transfer from 2 columns to a collapsed 1 column looks good as of right now. However, it is not quite functional in terms of what the user would want to see. Some of the articles at the top of Column B are more important than ones at bottom of A. I would more likely want to show something like:

```
A1
B1
A2
B2
A3
B3
|
An
Bn
```

What is the best way to accomplish this? I almost feel like I have to manipulate the DOM depending on screen width to place the articles in the right spot but I don't want to do this.

Excerpt of my HTML:

```
<div id="body" class="clearfix">
    <div id="primaryArticleBlock">
        <div id="article1"></div>
        <div id="article2"></div> 
        <div id="article3"></div>                      
    </div>
    <div id="secondaryArticleBlock">
        <div id="article4"></div>
        <div id="article5"></div>
        <div id="article6"></div>            
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: HTML structure is important here to answer.

Comment: I'd suggest using a grid system (see getbootstrap.com or foundation.zurb.com)

Comment: A grid system like @sventschui suggested would probably be best. Take a look at this http://www.layoutit.com/build?r=43964896

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to approach it, loosely related to the grid suggestions from others: http://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/OMOmZY

The general idea is that you restructure your content so that An and Bn are together on the same row, then use media queries to manipulipulate these row elements and set them to be full width as the viewport narrows.

You'll also need to use a [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) on each row so that all the elements clear correctly

**HTML**

```
...  
<div class="row cf">
    <div class="left">article1</div>
    <div class="right">article4</div>
</div>
...
```

**CSS**

```
.left{
  width: 60%;
  float:left;
}
.right{
  width:30%;
  float:left;
}


@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .right{
    width:100%;
  }

  .left{
    width:100%;
  }
}
```

Good luck!